# Meaning of "the usual 'get to know you' banter"

Tags: meaning

What exactly does "'get to know you' banter" mean in this phrase:

> Emma arrives. Their dialogue consists primarily of the usual “get to know you” banter.

Comment: What part don't you understand? The phrase "get to know you" is enclosed in "scare quotes" to indicate that it's being used in a way that goes beyond the bounds of standard syntax (specifically, it's a "verb phrase" being used as an ***adjective***). Such usages are often hyphenated as well as / instead of being "air quoted". Do you understand *"I want to **get to know you**"*, for example?

Comment: Also known as small talk.

Comment: Thank you @YosefBaskin, your explanation was clear.

Comment: Please add detail of what you don't understand.  Please tell us the source of the quote.  In it's current form, it is not suitable for [ell.se]

Comment: @FumbleFingers Or maybe they know both, but didn't understand how *get to know you banter* fits together grammatically.

Comment: Or maybe lots of other things.  So we should hold off answering until we know a little more.

Comment: @gotube: Apparently not - I alluded to the "unusual" grammar in my comment, but it was Yosef's "synonym" (?!) that hit the spot for OP!

Comment: I’m with @JamesK on this one. Besides, we claim not to be a dictionary site, and the meaning of each of *get to know* and *banter* is but a single web search away from anyone who looks.

Answer (score 2):

To "*get to know*" somebody means to spend time with them, usually talking about your lives, interests and views.

The adjective version of this verb is "*get-to-know-you*". The "you" doesn't refer to anyone in particular. It's just a word acting as the object of "know" so it sounds better.

In that quote, it should have been hyphenated, rather than put in quotes:

> Emma arrives. Their dialogue consists primarily of the usual **get-to-know-you** banter.

It's an adjective that modifies "banter". Together, "*get-to-know-you banter*" means the type of conversation that's common when getting to know someone, so topics like, *family status, occupation, personal interests, recent events, sports, politics*, etc.

Comment: I think it's a stylistic choice whether to "scare quote" or hyphenate (*both* seems excessive, though) On the first page of matches in Google Books for [**stick in the mud person**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22stick+in+the+mud+person%22) there were two or more hits for three orthographies: hyphenated, quoted, and unpunctuated (none for hyphenated *and* quoted, praise be! :)